# Will write() fail in this case using pipes?

Tags: c, pipe

If you fork() and create two processes for reading and writing to a pipe and the child process is reading from the pipe and the parent process is writing to the pipe, will writing in the parent process fail if the child process was to close the pipe that writes before the parent process has a chance to write to the pipe?

Comment: Attaching a code example will make the question look better.

Comment: I don't see what value a code example would add. The question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child process closing its write end of the pipe only removes its reference to the pipe, it doesn't cause the pipe to "shut down" or any such thing, and thus won't affect the parent's reference to it in any way. This is true for the `close(2)` call in general.

Further reading:

- [File descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)